# Undercooked cookies

Tags: baking, cookies

I made chocolate-chip cookies from a store-bought mix. I followed all of the directions and added the ingredients as directed. All I had to add was one egg and a 1/2 cup of softened butter.

I put the batch in for the recommended amount of time, at the recommended temperature (375F), but wasn't paying attention when I took them out. When I came back to check on them after they had cooled, I realized they were undercooked and still very doughy.

Is there anything I can do to salvage them? Should i pop them back in the oven for a while or toss them?

Comment: You may also want to get an oven thermometer, and confirm your oven isn't running cool.

Comment: @derobert It is an old oven, beat up oven in an outdated house we rent so that is likely the problem. I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: Second on the oven thermometer.  Baking is just applied chemistry, so everything has to be right for consistent results.  You may have to 'recalibrate' your temp gauge once you see what temperatures are working.  Once you have that down, get an old pizza stone or fire-place brick and place it at the bottom of your oven. It will take a little longer to heat up, but it will also help retain the heat if you are opening and closing the oven for multiple batches of cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undercooked cookies are still edible, don't toss them! Some people prefer chocolate chip cookies underdone, but you can't know for sure that the egg has fully cooked (although that wouldn't bother me one bit unless the source was shaky). If you must have them crisper, or if the remote possibility that the egg is unsafe concerns you, then yes, go ahead and put them back in the oven. They probably won't be as good as if they were perfectly timed to begin with, but it'll work.

Comment: Are they still safe to eat?

Comment: I can't say with absolute certainty that the egg in undercooked cookies will be safe, although undercooked eggs don't make me the slightest bit nervous. If you cook the cookies to crispness, then yes, they will be safe to eat.

Comment: I put them back in for a few minutes and they seem fine now. Thank you. :) I do enjoy moist, chewy cookies, but these were like eating  warm raw dough. :p

Comment: I'm glad you didn't throw them away! :)